How to fix This error: Password Failed authentication user Postgres
hello everyone i trying to make todo list app using React js PostgreSQL node js and express js i successfully connect with my database i create TABLE and I i INSERT the data the in my server.js file i create post method and when i get access in my browser localhost:8000/todos i get this error as you guys can see in the picture.

Here is all my code:
// this is my database 
CREATE DATABASE todoapp;
CREATE TABLE todos( id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, user_email VARCHAR(255), title VARCHAR(30), progress INT, date VARCHAR(300) );

CREATE TABLE users(email VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, hashed_password VARCHAR(255) );

// .env file code
USERNAME= postgres,
PASSWORD=james,
HOST=localhost,
DBPORT=5432


// server.js file code
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); 
const pool = require("./db");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.get("/todos", async (req, res) =>{
try {
const todos = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todos");     res.json(todos.rows);
} catch (error) {console.log(error);   
} });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`); });


// when i access in the browser
localhost:8000/todos/

i got this error:
error: password authentication failed for user "IRHA TRADERS"
Please help to solve this problem it really take a long time i searching from 2 days

The error seems to be because of invalid password
For rectifying the issue
Firstly, Please search for any occurrence of "IRHA TRADERS" in your code base, code might be taking that user
Second, Please ensure that USERNAME from env is taken and passed in pg pool
I won't be able to suggest a fix with partial code. But I can provide you a sample on usage of pg pool
s = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'dev',
  password: 'dev',
  port: 5440,
  database: 'dbaname',
  schema: 'schema',
  driver: 'pg',
  connectionLimit: 10
}
pool = new pg.Pool(s)

//querying

pool.connect().then((c) => {
  client = c;
  return client.query(...args);
}).then((result) => {
  client.release();
  return result;
}).catch((err) => {
  if (client) {
    client.release();
  }
  throw err;
});

Hope this helps
